# Converting from byte[] to String then String to byte[] gives different values

Tags: java

I am converting a byte array to String like so:

```
public String EncryptMessage(String str) {
    byte[] x = encryptMsg(str);
    String result = new String(x);
    return result;
}
```

then from String to byte[] like so:

```
String result  = encryption.EncryptMessage(qrCode);
byte[] bytes = result.getBytes();
```

But somehow it gives me two different values when converting to bytes. But I am sure that the string are the same. Can you please show me what's wrong? I am implementing this on Android.

Comment: Parameter of EncryptMessage is "str", however you are trying to encrypt "secret". Those are two different variables.

Comment: String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: @Cemil Sorry it was just a typo when I made it simpler to shorten it.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 what encrpytMsg() func returns?

Comment: It returns a byte array

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what is going wrong in your example without knowing the definition of encryptMsg. The following code performs as you would expect:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String string = "This is a string";
        byte[] byte_array = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // The following line prints the text "This is a string"
        System.out.println(new String(byte_array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Notice that the character encoding being translated from and to is explicitly stated in both the call to getBytes and the call to the String constructor. This may be the cause of your problem. The short explanation is that a character encoding defines a way to map from characters to underlying numbers, and are sometimes incompatible with each other, but see [this blog post](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for a more verbose explanation.

On a separate note, it looks like you may be rolling your own encryption. This is generally not a good idea, as encryption algorithms are very sensitive to tiny mistakes, many of which are difficult to spot without years of training - and even then, it is easy to make mistakes. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) on Information Security Stack Exchange for more about what can go wrong.